# How to read ONCE from firebase (without updating)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app which should read a child from firebase database first then store the keys of its children in an array. After that I wrote function to write new values into the same child which I was reading from in firebase.

I want the read function reads once only and not update itself as it did now. I wanna get the first values not what the writeFunction wrote.

EX:
in my firebase:
Movie{
242: "Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle"
342: "Thor: Ragnarok"
}

at my code:

```
    func readOldMovieID(){
       ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    ref?.child("users").child(userID!).child("Movie").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
         print("read Key:")
            print(snapshot.key)
                self.lastMovie.append(snapshot.key)

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

I tried different cods to make this function read one! but I think that I still unable to find the right one.

Comment: Does `observeSingleEvent(of: .value)` works for you? It will only read once and removes the observer.

Comment: It doesn't work as it should. the lastMovie array is updating when the values on firebase are updated.

Comment: I called the readFunction on viewLoad once

Comment: I just notice that in my app the child Movie might be not exist in firebase and as a result the read function works after writing function. So I am going to write a condition if the child is not exist then keep the array empty.

Comment: Just to be on the same page, you tried calling with `.value`, not `.childAdded`, right?

Answer (score 0):

checking if the child exist before read is solved the problem.
Thanks all